# Access a property of a sometimes null object without an error

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I often want to access the attribute of an object that may not exist.

For example:

`var foo = someObject.myProperty`

However this will throw an error if someObject is not defined. What is the conventional way to access properties of potentially null objects, and simply return false or null if it does not exist?

In Ruby, I can do `someObject.try(:myProperty)`. Is there a JS equivalent?

Comment: To check if its type is undefined is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct equivalent of what you are asking in JavaScript. But we can write some util methods that does the same thing.

```
Object.prototype.safeGet = function(key) {
    return this? this[key] : false;
}
var nullObject = null;
console.log(Object.safeGet.call(nullObject, 'invalid'));
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LBsY7/1/

Comment: handy handy handy, thanks

Comment: `Object.prototype.safeGet` crashes botbuilder for me.. strange...

Answer (score 2):

If it's a frequent request for you, you may create a function that checks it, like

```
function getValueOfNull(obj, prop) {
  return( obj == null ? undefined : obj[prop] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
 if(typeof someObject != 'undefined')
    var foo = someObject.myProperty
 else 
    return false; //or whatever
```

You can also add control on the `property` too, with:

```
if(someObject.myProperty)
```

clearly inside the first `if`

Or ('maybe' less correct)

```
if(someObject)
    var foo = someObject.myProperty
```

the second example should work because `undefined` is recognized as a `falsy` `value`

Comment: I think Don asks for a single line context, "if" context is obvious